# vb.net arcobjects determine whether arcmap is in editing session

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, esri-geodatabase, vb.net, topology

I have a vb.net arcmap addin which provide a function to validate geodb topology. But there is a problem, when I am not in editing session and use the function, arcmap will crash. In this case I intend to check whether the map is in editing session.

Is there a way to check whether arcmap is in editing session?

I am using vb.net and arcmap 10.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for the [EditState](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0020000000s9000000) on the editor extension.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jay, It works! I have put my code below in case it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

After Jay's help, I have successfully check when arcmap is in editing session, the code is as floows:

```
    Dim editorUid As New UID()
    editorUid.Value = "esriEditor.Editor"
    m_editor = TryCast(My.ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(editorUid), IEditor3)
    m_editEvents = TryCast(m_editor, IEditEvents_Event)
    If m_editor.EditState = esriEditState.esriStateNotEditing Then
        MsgBox("You must in editing session to validate the topology")
    End If
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the VB AddIn's but for CSharp, the  first 3 lines are duplicate what is in the ArcMap class (internal static class found in your AddIn's namespace), which already exposes an IEditor for AddIn editor extensions.